# Not enough space on disk when translating this enormous SQL Query

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to use Spark SQL to translate this SQL query using dataframes, but I am confused:

```
SELECT     E.DESDE_DT,
             U.UNADM_ID,
             U.ACTIV_ID,
             G.UNGES_ID,
             L.ELMUN_ID,
             F.UNFAC_ID,
             R.TPREC_ID,
             S.TPENT_ID,
             coalesce( TF.TPGFA_ID,  S.TPENT_ID,  TF.TPGFA_ID ) TPGFA_ID,
             coalesce(TP.PROCE_ID, 0, TP.PROCE_ID) PROCE_ID,
             V.PROVE_NM,coalesce(OPERADOR_ID,0) OPERADOR_ID,
            SUM(E.POBIN_QT) * coalesce(POBDC_QT,1) as POBDC_QT ,
             SUM(E.POBLA_QT) * coalesce(POBDC_QT,1) as POBGC_QT,
              PORCENTAJE_QT, -- PORCENTAJE DEL OPERADOR
              isnull(UTE_ID,0) AS UTE_ID,
             PORCENTAJE_UTE_QT,OP.MEDIOSPP_SN
      FROM DWE_VM_UAACTIVI U,
           DWE_VM_UGACTMUN M,
           DWE_VM_ENTLOCAL L,
           DWE_VM_UFUGACTI F right join  DWE_SGE_SAP_PROVEEDORES V on V.PROVE_ID = F.UNFAC_ID,
           DWE_VM_UFTRGMUN T,
           DWE_VM_POBPERST P,
           DWE_VM_TIPOLENT S,
           DWE_VM_COMUAUTO C,
           DWE_VM_TPRECOGI TP,
           DWE_VM_UNIDADMI UA ,
         (SELECT * FROM DWE_VM_TIPOLFAC TP
            WHERE (TP.DESDE_DT BETWEEN cast ('2017-07-01' as date )  AND cast ('2017-07-31' as date )
                    OR (TP.DESDE_DT <= cast ('2017-07-01' as date )
                    AND (TP.HASTA_DT >= cast ('2017-07-01' as date )  OR TP.HASTA_DT IS NULL)))) TF
                    right join  DWE_VM_ENTLTPRE R on TF.ELMUN_ID = R.ELMUN_ID,
         DWE_VM_UFUGACTI UF left join  DWE_VM_UGACTIVI G on UF.UGACT_ID = G.UGACT_ID--,
                            left join DWE_VM_ELTREPOB E on (UF.DESDE_DT <= E.HASTA_DT  and isnull(UF.HASTA_DT, E.DESDE_DT) >= E.DESDE_DT)
                            right join DWE_SGE_SAP_PROVEEDORES V2 on V2.PROVE_ID = uF.UNFAC_ID ,
             (
             select (1 * coalesce(OP.PORCENTAJE_QT, 100) / 100) * coalesce(OU.PORCENTAJE_QT, 100) / 100 AS POBDC_QT,
                       OP.OPERADOR_ID OPERADOR_ID_OP, OU.OPERADOR_ID OPERADOR_ID_OU,
             COALESCE(OP.OPERADOR_ID, OU.OPERADOR_ID, 0) AS OPERADOR_ID,
             CASE WHEN OP.OPERADOR_ID IS NOT NULL THEN OP.PORCENTAJE_QT
                  ELSE OU.PORCENTAJE_QT
             END PORCENTAJE_QT,
             coalesce(OP.UTE_ID,0) AS UTE_ID,
             CASE WHEN OP.UTE_ID IS NOT NULL THEN OP.PORCENTAJE_QT
                  ELSE NULL
             END AS PORCENTAJE_UTE_QT ,OP.DESDE_DT,OP.HASTA_DT, OP.UFUGA_ID,OP.MEDIOSPP_SN
             from DWE_SGR_MU_ASIG_OPERADORES_UTE_TMP OU  left join DWE_SGR_MU_ASIG_OPERADORES_UF_TMP OP on OP.UTE_ID = OU.UTE_ID
             )  OP right join  DWE_VM_UFUGACTI UF2 on UF2.UFUGA_ID = OP.UFUGA_ID
      WHERE U.UAACT_ID = G.UAACT_ID
        AND G.UGACT_ID = M.UGACT_ID
        AND M.ELMUN_ID = L.ELMUN_ID
        AND G.UGACT_ID = F.UGACT_ID
        AND F.UFUGA_ID = T.UFUGA_ID
        AND T.MUNTR_ID = R.MUNTR_ID
        AND R.ELMUN_ID = L.ELMUN_ID
        AND T.UFTRG_ID = E.UFTRG_ID
        AND F.UFUGA_ID = P.UFUGA_ID
        AND P.DESDE_DT = E.DESDE_DT
        AND UA.UNADM_ID = U.UNADM_ID
        AND UA.COMAU_ID = C.COMAU_ID
        AND S.ELMUN_ID = L.ELMUN_ID
        AND TP.TPREC_ID = R.TPREC_ID
        AND V2.PROVE_ID= V.PROVE_ID
        and UF2.UFUGA_ID= P.UFUGA_ID
        and UF2.UGACT_ID =UF.UGACT_ID
        AND (G.DESDE_DT BETWEEN cast ('2017-07-01' as date )  AND cast ('2017-07-31' as date )
          OR (G.DESDE_DT <= cast ('2017-07-01' as date )
            AND (G.HASTA_DT >= cast ('2017-07-01' as date )  OR G.HASTA_DT IS NULL)))
        AND (M.DESDE_DT BETWEEN cast ('2017-07-01' as date )  AND cast ('2017-07-31' as date )
          OR (M.DESDE_DT <= cast ('2017-07-01' as date )
            AND (M.HASTA_DT >= cast ('2017-07-01' as date )  OR M.HASTA_DT IS NULL)))
        AND (T.DESDE_DT BETWEEN cast ('2017-07-01' as date )  AND cast ('2017-07-31' as date )
          OR (T.DESDE_DT <= cast ('2017-07-01' as date )
           AND (T.HASTA_DT >= cast ('2017-07-01' as date )  OR T.HASTA_DT IS NULL)))
        AND (R.DESDE_DT BETWEEN cast ('2017-07-01' as date )  AND cast ('2017-07-31' as date )
          OR (R.DESDE_DT <= cast ('2017-07-01' as date )
           AND (R.HASTA_DT >= cast ('2017-07-01' as date )  OR R.HASTA_DT IS NULL)))
        AND (T.DESDE_DT <= E.DESDE_DT
            AND (T.HASTA_DT >= E.HASTA_DT OR T.HASTA_DT IS NULL))
        AND (S.DESDE_DT <= E.DESDE_DT
            AND (S.HASTA_DT >= E.HASTA_DT OR S.HASTA_DT IS NULL))
        AND U.ACTIV_ID IN (1, 2)
        AND E.VERSI_ID = (SELECT MAX(P2.VERSI_ID)
                          FROM DWE_VM_ELTREPOB P2
                          WHERE P2.UFTRG_ID = E.UFTRG_ID
                            AND P2.DESDE_DT = E.DESDE_DT)
        AND E.DESDE_DT >= cast ('2017-07-01' as date )
        AND E.DESDE_DT <= cast ('2017-07-31' as date )
GROUP BY E.DESDE_DT,
             U.UNADM_ID,
             U.ACTIV_ID,
             G.UNGES_ID,
             L.ELMUN_ID,
             F.UNFAC_ID,
             R.TPREC_ID,
             S.TPENT_ID,
             TF.TPGFA_ID,
             TP.PROCE_ID,E.POBIN_QT, E.POBLA_QT,--OPERADOR_ID_OP, OPERADOR_ID_OU,
             OPERADOR_ID,
            V.PROVE_NM,POBDC_QT,PORCENTAJE_QT,coalesce(UTE_ID,0),PORCENTAJE_QT, 
             isnull(UTE_ID,0),
             PORCENTAJE_UTE_QT,OP.MEDIOSPP_SN
```

I've tried to translate some of the code to Spark SQL but I have some problems regarding the fact that I get the following error:

22/09/28 18:51:55 ERROR DiskBlockObjectWriter: Uncaught exception while reverting partial writes to file C:\Users\fchaconh\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-5522b418-9b11-4aba-bc16-5bf839aa3208\39\temp_shuffle_ed23177b-3f40-4766-bbdd-f86a3cde571d
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\fchaconh\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-5522b418-9b11-4aba-bc16-5bf839aa3208\39\temp_shuffle_ed23177b-3f40-4766-bbdd-f86a3cde571d (There is not enough space on the disk)

Here you have some of the code that I tried to develop:

```
val TP=spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("DWE_VM_TIPOLFAC_20220624_174344.csv.bz2")

val R = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("DWE_VM_ENTLTPRE_20220624_172757.csv.bz2")

val OP= spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("DWE_SGR_MU_ASIG_OPERADORES_UF_TMP_20220624_165920.csv.bz2")

val OU = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("DWE_SGR_MU_ASIG_OPERADORES_UTE_TMP_20220624_165929.csv.bz2")

val U = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("DWE_VM_UAACTIVI_20220624_174209.csv.bz2")

val G = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("DWE_VM_UGACTIVI_20220624_174307.csv.bz2")

val M = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("DWE_VM_UGACTMUN_20220624_174425.csv.bz2")

val L= spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("DWE_VM_ENTLOCAL_20220624_171535.csv.bz2")

val F = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("DWE_VM_UFUGACTI_20220624_174339.csv.bz2")

val T = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("DWE_VM_UFTRGMUN_20220624_174447.csv.bz2")

val E= spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("DWE_VM_ELTREPOB_20220624_172746.csv.bz2")

val P = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("DWE_VM_POBPERST_20220624_172950.csv.bz2")

val UA = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("DWE_VM_UNIDADMI_20220624_174438.csv.bz2")

val C = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("DWE_VM_COMUAUTO_20220624_171044.csv.bz2")

val S = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("DWE_VM_TIPOLENT_20220624_174014.csv.bz2")

val TPEXT= spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("DWE_VM_TPRECOGI_20220624_174341.csv.bz2")

val V = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("DWE_SGE_SAP_PROVEEDORES_20220624_165906.csv.bz2")
  .select(col("PROVE_ID"))

C.show()
UA.show()
M.show()

///FILTER

val TF=TP.where(TP("DESDE_DT").between("2017-07-01","2017-07-31")
or(TP("DESDE_DT")<=("2017-07-01") and (TP("HASTA_DT")>=("2017-07-01") or TP("HASTA_DT").isNull)))

val OPEXT=OU.join(OP,OP("UTE_ID")===OU("UTE_ID"),"left")
  .select(((lit(1) * coalesce(OP("PORCENTAJE_QT"), lit(100)) / 100) *
    (coalesce(OU("PORCENTAJE_QT"), lit(100)) / 100)).as("POBDC_QT")
  ,OP("OPERADOR_ID").as("OPERADOR_ID_OP"),OU("OPERADOR_ID").as("OPERADOR_ID_OU")
  ,coalesce(OP("OPERADOR_ID"), OU("OPERADOR_ID"),lit(0)).as("OPERADOR_ID")
  ,when(!isnull(OP("OPERADOR_ID")),OP("PORCENTAJE_QT")).otherwise(OU("PORCENTAJE_QT")).as("PORCENTAJE_QT")
  ,coalesce(OP("UTE_ID"),lit(0)).as("UTE_ID")
  ,when(!isnull(OP("UTE_ID")),OP("PORCENTAJE_QT")).otherwise(null).as("PORCENTAJE_UTE_QT")
  ,OP("DESDE_DT"),OP("HASTA_DT"),OP("UFUGA_ID"),OP("MEDIOSPP_SN"))

TF.show()
OPEXT.show()

////JOIN

val join_from_1=F.join(V,V("PROVE_ID")===F("UNFAC_ID"),"right")

join_from_1.show()

val join_from_2=TF.join(R,R("ELMUN_ID") === TF("ELMUN_ID"),"right")

join_from_2.show()

val join_from_3=F.join(V,V("PROVE_ID")===F("UNFAC_ID"),"right")
  .join(G,G("UGACT_ID")===F("UGACT_ID"),"left")
  .join(E,F("DESDE_DT")<=E("HASTA_DT") && coalesce(F("HASTA_DT"),E("DESDE_DT"))>=E("DESDE_DT"),"left")

join_from_3.show()

val join_from_4 = OPEXT.join(F, OPEXT("UFUGA_ID") === F("UFUGA_ID"), "right")

join_from_4.show()


val join3_G = join_from_3.select(G("*"))
val join1_F= join_from_1.select(F("*"))

U.join(join3_G,U("UAACT_ID")===join3_G("UAACT_ID"))
  .join(M,M("UGACT_ID")===join3_G("UGACT_ID"))
  .join(L,L("ELMUN_ID")===M("ELMUN_ID"))
  .join(join1_F,join1_F("UGACT_ID")===join3_G("UGACT_ID"))
  .join(T,join1_F("UFUGA_ID")===T("UFUGA_ID"))
  .show()
```

I have the problem in the last block of code, exactly, here:

```
U.join(join3_G,U("UAACT_ID")===join3_G("UAACT_ID"))
  .join(M,M("UGACT_ID")===join3_G("UGACT_ID"))
  .join(L,L("ELMUN_ID")===M("ELMUN_ID"))
  .join(join1_F,join1_F("UGACT_ID")===join3_G("UGACT_ID"))
  .join(T,join1_F("UFUGA_ID")===T("UFUGA_ID"))
  .show()
```

The computer slow down and I have the problem that I mentioned previously:

22/09/28 18:51:55 ERROR DiskBlockObjectWriter: Uncaught exception while reverting partial writes to file C:\Users\fchaconh\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-5522b418-9b11-4aba-bc16-5bf839aa3208\39\temp_shuffle_ed23177b-3f40-4766-bbdd-f86a3cde571d
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\fchaconh\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-5522b418-9b11-4aba-bc16-5bf839aa3208\39\temp_shuffle_ed23177b-3f40-4766-bbdd-f86a3cde571d (There is not enough space on the disk)

Maybe I can do this job with my computer because the .csv files are so big to make joins between them. All of them takes up less than 100 MB disk space.

I can upload the .csv files if you need it.

I cannot use spark.sql() sentence to do this job. It would be easier to do it but I cannot use that sentence.

Comment: Mixing implicit joins with an explicit right join - very confusing,

Comment: Hi jarlh. I don't understand you.

Comment: This code is bad.  It is using a technique that is 30 years old -- old style joins.  In addition in the middle of it there is a new style join using a RIGHT join.  RIGHT joins are rarely used because the convention is to normalize to left joins.  This does not mean it is wrong -- just that is is very hard to read code.

Comment: I understand that SQL code is difficult to read, but my intention is translate this code to Spark. SQL code is not mine.

Comment: If I was given this code to translate, the first thing I would do is refactor it in a way that made sense.  Having the old code to validate my refactoring.  Once I understood what the code was doing and had it written in a way that was good -- then I would translate it to spark.

Comment: The reason you are running out of disk space is because there is some kind of screwed up cross join like situation with the combination of left and right joins and the temporary space needed to store the data is a ^ b ^ c ^ d ^e ^ f -- where the letters represent the size of the tables you are querying.  This can be fixed but you need to refactor it first to understand how.

Comment: Hi Hogan, I've tried to change all left and right joins to inner joins and I have the same problem. The problem is with this code: U.join(join3_G,U("UAACT_ID")===join3_G("UAACT_ID"))
  .join(M,M("UGACT_ID")===join3_G("UGACT_ID"))
  .join(L,L("ELMUN_ID")===M("ELMUN_ID"))
  .join(join1_F,join1_F("UGACT_ID")===join3_G("UGACT_ID"))
  .join(T,join1_F("UFUGA_ID")===T("UFUGA_ID"))
  .show()

Comment: How can I refactor this code? What tools can I use for this?

Comment: Don't change the right joins to inner joins -- that probably does something you don't want to do.  I would not be able to refactor this without looking at the full database and running some tests

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248432/discussion-between-user2205174-and-hogan).

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is to understand the right joins

```
 right join  DWE_VM_UFUGACTI UF2 on UF2.UFUGA_ID = OP.UFUGA_ID
 right join DWE_VM_ENTLTPRE R on TF.ELMUN_ID = R.ELMUN_ID
 right join DWE_SGE_SAP_PROVEEDORES V2 on V2.PROVE_ID = uF.UNFAC_ID
 right join  DWE_SGE_SAP_PROVEEDORES V on V.PROVE_ID = F.UNFAC_ID
```

This is most likely to bethe cause of the size explostion you are seeing.  In a right join you INCLUDE every row on the right hand side even if there is no mathing data on the left.  This means all values for

```
DWE_VM_UFUGACTI.UFUGA_ID
```

are included.  How many rows is that?  Take that number of rows and multiply by the number of rows in the original table -- that is now rows the result is going to have.

That is true for all 4 of those right joins.

This could be a problem.  You have to look at the tables and see why.  If the tables only have one row -- then not a problem.  If they have 1k rows or more -- probably a problem.

Comment: No, nothing to do. The problem is not about left join or right join. I've replaced all joins for inner joins and the problem is the same. I already know that the query is not the same but I want to use another join for testing. The query is so slow that I have an error because the size explodes.

Comment: It's the most difficult problem I have had to solve. If you want I can send you the database files and take a look at. But I don't know how I can upload this files in stackoverflow.